# Motivation for $r$ in AKS Primality Test

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, primality-test

I've been reading up on the AKS primality test, and I understand the big ideas and proofs as they are pretty elementary number theory. I am confused about how to value of $r$ is selected. In the algorithm, the value of $r$ is chosen as such:

Find the smallest $r$ such that $o_r(n) > (log(n))^2$, where $n$ is the number we're checking to see if prime or not.

I've read several papers on the AKS test, but I still don't understand the motivation. Could you please explain to me why $r$ is defined as such?

Comment: The choice of $r$ is important for the algorithm to work - see  Lemma $3$ on the [existence of a good $r$](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/the-aks-primality-test/).

Comment: ah ok, could you explain what it means when it says $r<= O(log(n)^O(1))$ ? I thought $ O(log(n)^O(1))$ is a time...